# C# Build Errors- Debug Target is Missing

Tags: visual-studio

I am just starting out with Visual Studios. When I try to run any code I get the error. *There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?* When I click OK I get a bunch of errors saying access to the path has been denied. 
I have tried everything (ran as administrator, uninstalled and reinstalled, checked the path, made sure main/entry project has checked Build) Nothing is working and i'm very desperate for help.
https://gyazo.com/beb3dfc8d250f492e5dac054fb04273b
https://gyazo.com/0dbc199dd01f714e19197802902b0110

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015

Comment: Usually you get access denied if the file is use (can happen occasionally if your program exits abnormally and you have the debugger attached). Have you tried killing all Visual Studio related processes and/or restarting your computer?

Comment: Yes I restarted my computer and killed all visual studios items but I still get the error